# Passing a document entity to JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript, dom-events

This is an elementary problem (I think), and I am embarrassed to ask it here. It may have been answered already, but I could not find it my searches.

In its simplest form, there are two check-boxes, and each CheckBox has a control (e.g, TextBox or DropDownList) associated with it.  When the checked state of a CheckBox changes, the associated control must be enabled or disabled.

JavaScript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript:>
function enable(bValue, control)
{
   document.getElementByID(control).Enabled = bValue;
}
</script>
```

I'd call this function as an event procedure, e.g, `enable(this.Checked, "expJob")` and `enable(this.Checked, "itemJob")`, in the HTML below:

```
<body>
    Billable? <asp:CheckBox ID="expBillable" runat="server" Checked="false" OnCheckedChanged="enable(this.Checked, "expJob");" />
    to <asp:DropDownList ID="expJob" runat="server" Enabled="true" />
    <br /><br />
    Billable? <asp:CheckBox ID="itemBillable" runat="server" Checked="false" OnCheckedChanged="enable(this.Checked, "itemJob");" />
    to <asp:DropDownList ID="itemJob" runat="server" Enabled="true" />
</body>
```

The problem is that, because of the use of quotes, I am unable to specify the "expJob" parameter in the HTML.  Even the use of single quotes does not work.

So the question:  Will this approach work?  What is the proper syntax?

What is the best way to write and use a function such as this?  I am sure such function use will be required when having to iterate over the rows in a grid.

Interestingly, all the questions/answers I have seen use a control's disabled attribute.  I am only able to use the Enabled attribute.  Can someone explain why, and what the difference is?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the `"`s around expJob with `\\`s?

Comment: Yes, I tried to escape the quotes (\").  But the editor did not recognize it and still caused an error in the HTML document.

Comment: Does it have to do with interaction (and conflicts) between ASP tags and JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to use the single quotes ('itemJob')
2. I think OnCheckChanged is a server event. Asp.net needs a handler in the code behind when you want to use this. Thats why you are getting an error. Find the correct client side event when you want to fire a client side event. Take care of firing postbacks, but default for checkbox is "no auto postback" anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Please be aware that javascript is case sensitive so
`document.getElementById` is good,
`document.getElementByID` is bad (note the ID in caps is bad)